# How can I use SOAP (Savon) in Ruby? - Moving from PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I need to do this in Ruby:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => 'https://mydomain.com/index.php',
                                 'uri'      => 'https://mydomain.com/',
                                 'trace' => 1,
                                 'exceptions' => 1));
$id = $client->login($username,$password);
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Of course, I tried something. And I'm sure, it's easy. But I can't understand it. Endpoint is location and namespace is uri? And when I call client.call(:login, message: {"username, pass"} ) I need send only two parameters without username: "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Savon documentation is extremely detailed at [http://www.savonrb.com](http://savonrb.com). I'm sure you can find what you are looking for - you should at least try before resorting to asking here.

Comment: I tried it, but I think I was totally wrong.

Comment: @instack check your version. if you installed savon 2.x, the documentation is at savonrb.com/version2.html